# My Rails 6 background images isn't showing up on Heroku

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am new to **Ruby on Rails**. I've set a background image on a **Bootstrap jumbotron**.

The **CSS** looks like this:

```css
.jumbotron {
    background-image: url('/assets/Slide1');
}
```

This works because rails automatically makes the link: local/assets/Slide1.

However, when I push to **Heroku**, herokusite/assets/Slide 1 doesn't work.  Therefore my image doesn't work.  What do I do to resolve this?

Comment: Heroku doesn't store images or do file uploads, https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted to learn more about it,  so where are you storing the images?

Comment: Right now I have a copy as I've been trying to get it to work both in asset/image and javascriot/image

Answer (score 0):

I believe that may just be the wrong helper method you're attempting to use. I think `url` is a CSS helper so you can't actually point to a particular file as each asset will have a generated digest from rails when deploying.

So what you should try instead is

```
.jumbotron {
    background-image: asset-url('Slide1.jpg');
}
```

I added the `.jpg` the extension you'll need to update that one if it's not `jpg`. BTW, you will not need to specify the `/assets` path.

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#css-and-sass

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work:./  No errors, but the image no longer shows as background anymore.